trying to clean code yaml in dwains dashboard
I use Dwains Dashboard in Home Assistant
and I have this code for the more page addon
# dwains_dashboard

#More_page addon view 
{% if _dd_more_pages %}
{% for addon in _dd_more_pages %}
- title: {{ _dd_more_pages[addon]["name"] }}
  path: more_page_{{ addon|lower|replace("'", "_")|replace(" ", "_") }}
  type: custom:dwains-dashboard-layout
  icon: {{ _dd_more_pages[addon]["icon"] }}
  visible: true
  cards:    
    - type: custom:more-page-card
      name: {{ _dd_more_pages[addon]["name"] }}
      icon: {{ _dd_more_pages[addon]["icon"] }}
      show_in_navbar: {{ _dd_more_pages[addon]["show_in_navbar"] }}
      foldername: {{ addon }}
      card: !include ../../../../{{ _dd_more_pages[addon]["path"] }}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}

as you can see in the picture below, there are a lot of error messages

how can I clean that and should I clean it?
I try to add "" around the bracket on the lines that say missing comma but it generates a new error
